# Making the object created from Object.create have the correct Object.prototype.toString

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I was under the impression that Object.create is used, well for creating objects that have the specified prototype. That is true for instanceof, however, I run into this problem:

```
var arr = Object.create(Array.prototype);
console.log(arr instanceof Array); // true
console.log(Array.isArray(arr)); // false
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(arr)); // [object Object] 

var trueArr = [];
console.log(trueArr instanceof Array); // true
console.log(Array.isArray(trueArr)); // true
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(trueArr)); // [object Array]
```

As you can see, the Array.isArray call fails on the arr created from Object.create and that is because internally, Array.isArray calls Object.prototype.toString.call(arr) which is [object Object] instead of [object Array]. My question is that is there anyway to make it so that the object created from Object.create have the desired Object.prototype.toString behaviour? ( returning [Object Array] )

Comment: Interesting edge case.

Comment: Have you read this [article](http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/) by kangax?

Comment: I've posted my answer on the duplicate question now